# How to remove displayed value from td and replace with input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic table that display names and input fields. If name is displayed in table row user have option to delete that name. I know how to remove value from specific table row but I have problem replacing that same spot with input field that should be the same as other available fields. Here is my code that I have so far:

```
<cfoutput>
     <tr>
        <td>#TimeFormat(CurrentTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
        <td onClick="deleteSlot('#TimeSlotID#')">
            <cfif UserID GT 0>
                <label>
                    <div id="#TimeSlotID#">
                        (<b>#First# #Last#</b>)
                        <img src="images/delete.png"/>
                    </div>
                </label>
            <cfelseif UserID EQ -1>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email#currentRow#" class="email">
                    <input type="button" name="slot" id="slot#currentRow#" class="slot" value="Save" onClick="saveTime(this,'#TimeSlotID#')" style="display: none">
                </label>
            </cfif>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </cfoutput>
```

JavaScript:
//This code display save button if user start typing in available field.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".email").keyup(function(e) {
                if($(this).val() != '') {
                    $(".email").not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $(this).next(".slot").show();
                } else {
                    $(".email").removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(this).next(".slot").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

//This is the code where I'm trying to remove name from the cell and replace with input field

```
 function deleteSlot(TimeSlotID){
      $('#' + TimeSlotID).replaceWith('<label><input type="text" name="email" id="email#currentRow#" class="email"><input type="button" name="slot" id="slot#currentRow#" class="slot" value="Save" onClick="saveTime(this,'#TimeSlotID#')" style="display: none"></label>');
  }
```

This code that I currently use in deleteSlot function does replace name with input field but if I start typing in that field I do not have Save button showed up like in the others. I'm not 100% sure if this can be done the way I started or I should use something else. I tried append but that did not work, gave me extra input fields every time I clicked. If anyone knows better way to fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the event keyup needs to be re-applied:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  applyKeyUp();
});
function applyKeyUp() {
    $(".email").keyup(function(e) {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $(".email").not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            $(this).next(".slot").show();
        } else {
            $(".email").removeAttr('disabled');
            $(this).next(".slot").hide();
        }
    });
}
function deleteSlot(TimeSlotID){
  $('#' + TimeSlotID).replaceWith('<label><input type="text" name="email" id="email#currentRow#" class="email"><input type="button" name="slot" id="slot#currentRow#" class="slot" value="Save" onClick="saveTime(this,'#TimeSlotID#')" style="display: none"></label>');
  applyKeyUp();

}
```

Comment: So I have a question about solution that I was thinking about since I have more staff that I should pass to deleteSlot function and it makes everything more complex. What if I grab label with two inputs and set above inside of that div where name is displayed, and set style to display:none. After user click on the delete image first name should be removed and then attribute display:none. Does this make sense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would work, unless the issue of .keyup event not being tied anymore when you replace the code. My guess was the new code you inserted did not have the keyup event attached because it happened after you applied it in your doc.ready call.  You could change the code to always have the input field in the DOM, but just use display:none.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking about. Works fine I tried. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with weirdness of the id you are passing.Since the `id` is already having `'#'` in front of it, the jquery selector would not be able to apply the `target by id`. If you really need `'#'` in front of the id, then you need to apply `id equal to` selector.

```
 $('#' + TimeSlotID)
```

should be

```
$("[id = '" + TimeSlotID + "']")
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/5/